# Set an array of items from a php app in a html <select> items inside a twig template

Tags: php, html, arrays, twig, slim

I have a PHP application using SLIM as the router and controller and it returns items as an array and I need them to be set as a html  items inside a twig template with no repetition here is what I'm doing

```
            {% for cat in categories %}
              Category <select name="category" >
                <option  value="category"> {{ cat.category_name }} </option>      
              </select>     
            {% endfor %}
```

but this makes the select items drop-down to appear the number of categories I have for each on it's own drop-down e.g two or three. What I want is to have all of them in the drop-down and then the user can select one after they are loaded.

shown here
[image: both showing]
help appreciated.

Comment: use for inside select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   Category <select name="category" >       
   {% for cat in categories %}

        <option  value="category"> {{ cat.category_name }} </option>      
        {% endfor %}        
  </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Already found the answer so it was a matter of removing the category name from inside the for loop

```
    Category <select name="category" >
     {% for cat in categories %}    
         <option  value="category"> {{ cat.category_name }} </option>               
     {% endfor %}
     </select>
```